# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null Exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am trying to plot the routes using DirectionService API by supplying waypoints (greater than 8). As DirectionService API allow maximum of 8 waypoints (for general use), I am recursively making call to process waypoint, 8 points at a time.

Whenever it tries to plot the route in "setDirections" method, its throwing error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null".

JavaScript Code (geojson_2.js) :

```
function RouteService(oGoogleMaps, oMap) {
    var requestArray = [], renderArray = [], data, limit, index = 0, MAX_WAY_POINT_ALLOWED = 20;
    var directionService = new oGoogleMaps.DirectionsService({
        map: oMap
    });
    var nextRequest = function () {
        index++;
        if (index >= requestArray.length) {
            return;
        }
        makeRequests(requestArray[index]);
    };

    this.getVariables = function (sVariable) {
        return eval(sVariable);
    };

    var directionResults = function (result, status) {
        if (status == oGoogleMaps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

            // Create a unique DirectionsRenderer 'i'
            renderArray[index] = new oGoogleMaps.DirectionsRenderer();

            // Some unique options from the colorArray so we can see the routes
            renderArray[index].setOptions({
                preserveViewport: true,
                suppressInfoWindows: true,
                polylineOptions: {
                    strokeWeight: 4,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8
                },
                markerOptions: {
                    icon: {
                        path: oGoogleMaps.SymbolPath.BACKWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
                        scale: 3
                    }
                },
                map : oMap
            });

            // Use this new renderer with the result
            renderArray[index].setDirections(result);

        }
        nextRequest();
    };

    var makeRequests = function (oRequest) {
        directionService.route(oRequest.request, directionResults);
    };

    this.generateRequests = function (oResponseData) {
        requestArray = [];
        var lastpoint = null, waypts = [];
        for (var waypoint = 0, limit = oResponseData.length; waypoint < limit; waypoint++) {
            if (lastpoint && (lastpoint.lng() === oResponseData[waypoint].lng() && lastpoint.lat() === oResponseData[waypoint].lat())) {
                // Duplicate of of the last waypoint - don't process
                continue;
            }
            lastpoint = oResponseData[waypoint]

            waypts.push({
                location: oResponseData[waypoint],
                stopover: true
            });
        }
        var start, finish, routeIndex = 0, maxRequest = Math.ceil(oResponseData.length / MAX_WAY_POINT_ALLOWED);

        for (var pointCount = 0; routeIndex < maxRequest; routeIndex++, pointCount = pointCount + MAX_WAY_POINT_ALLOWED) {
            var tempWayPts = waypts.slice(pointCount, pointCount + MAX_WAY_POINT_ALLOWED);
            // Grab the first waypoint for the 'start' location
            start = (tempWayPts.shift()).location;
            // Grab the last waypoint for use as a 'finish' location
            finish = tempWayPts.pop();
            if (finish === undefined) {
                // Unless there was no finish location for some reason?
                finish = start;
            } else {
                finish = finish.location;
            }

            var request = {
                origin: start,
                destination: finish,
                waypoints: tempWayPts,
                travelMode: oGoogleMaps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            requestArray.push({"routeIndex": routeIndex, "request": request});
        }

        makeRequests(requestArray[index]);
    }
};

function MapService() {

    var routeService = null;
    var oGoogleMaps = google.maps, oMap, oMapOptions = {
        minZoom: 2,
        zoom: 3,
        panControl: true,
        panControlOptions: {
            position: oGoogleMaps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
        },
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: oGoogleMaps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
            position: oGoogleMaps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
        },
        scaleControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        overviewMapControl: true,
        mapTypeId: oGoogleMaps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: [
            {
                featureType: "water",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [{
                    color: '#4eb4e5'
                }, {
                    saturation: -10
                }, {
                    lightness: 40
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "road",
                stylers: [{
                    hue: '#ffc000'
                }, {
                    saturation: -30
                }, {
                    lightness: 10
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "poi",
                stylers: [{
                    hue: '#8CC63F'
                }, {
                    saturation: -10
                }, {
                    lightness: 10
                }]
            }]
    };

    this.getVariables = function (sVariable) {
        var result;
        if ((result = eval(sVariable)) != undefined) {
            result = routeService.getVariables(sVariable);
        }
        return result;
    };

    this.loadMap = function (targetDiv) {
        oMap = new oGoogleMaps.Map(document.getElementById(targetDiv), oMapOptions);
        routeService = new RouteService(oGoogleMaps, oMap);
        //plotRoutes(oMap);
        //some = oMap.data.addGeoJson(oPolyLinePath);
        // To delete the path
        // oMap.data.remove(some[0]);
    };

    this.plotRoutes = function () {
        var oRouteMap = [
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.968313", "-95.4155288"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9673186", "-95.40616060000002"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9658338", "-95.4150376"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9682822", "-95.4153981"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9679707", "-95.41517220000003"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9679707", "-95.41517220000003"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9682842", "-95.41553049999999"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9682842", "-95.41553049999999"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9682877", "-95.41551320000002"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9682707", "-95.41550280000001"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9682878", "-95.4155169"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9682721", "-95.41551179999999"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9682784", "-95.41550799999999"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9682884", "-95.41551449999997"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.968295", "-95.41549050000003"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9682868", "-95.41547450000002"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9682774", "-95.41546470000003"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9682871", "-95.4154163"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9683139", "-95.41551659999999"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9683222", "-95.4155614"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9683159", "-95.41555370000003"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9683428", "-95.41555949999997"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9683213", "-95.41557449999999"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9683153", "--95.4155255"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9683094", "-95.4155313"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9683223", "-95.41553329999999"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.9682942", "-95.41538589999999"),
            new oGoogleMaps.LatLng("29.965987", "-95.40982959999997")
        ];
        routeService.generateRequests(oRouteMap);
    }
};


$(document).ready(function () {
    var mapService = new MapService();
    mapService.loadMap("mapDiv");
    mapService.plotRoutes();
});
```

HTML Code :

```
<div id="mapDiv"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=weather,places&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="geojson_2.js"></script>
```

Can anyone please help me out of this.

Thanks

Comment: somehow one of your points is "null" instead of a LatLng object, that's why the method fails to read its latitude.

Comment: Agreed, at least one of the items in `oResponseData` would appear not to be a LatLng object.

Answer (score 0):

Something to try - compose `waypts` with `oResponseData.reduce()` as follows :

```
var waypts = oResponseData.reduce(function(a, waypoint) {
    var lastpoint = a[a.length - 1];
    if( !lastpoint || !waypoint.equals(lastpoint.location) ) {
        a.push({ location:waypoint, stopover:true });
    }
    return a;
}, []);
```

This should be more reliable though I'm not sure if it will fix the problem. You could just end up with an empty array without an error having been thrown.